# Will GraphQL subscriptions push changes if the change is made not through GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, graphql-subscriptions

If I have a type :

```
type Todo {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  desc: String!
}
```

and mutations to create and get list of Todo objects : 
`createTodo`, and `getListTodo` 
everything is good so far. 
I noticed , the subscription, say :

> `onCreateTodo`,
> only works as an effect of createTodo.
> subscription does not push new data, if I manually push a record in the DB.

is that how its supposed to work?
I am using dynamodb and appsync with amplify .

Answer (score 1):

> is that how its supposed to work?

Yes, that is how its supposed to work.
But you can achieve the desired functionality by utilising the database's [native subscription](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html), referred to as streams. You should be able to emit changes to subscribers, although it would take a bit of work to get done

Comment: i routed all mutations through a  graphql client with lambda. Works for my use case.